# how to know when a device unlocks using the LockApplicationHost class in winRT apps

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-runtime, win-universal-app

here's what I've done in my universal windows app:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();                
    private LockApplicationHost lol=LockApplicationHost.GetForCurrentView();
}
private async void Lol_Unlocking(LockApplicationHost sender, LockScreenUnlockingEventArgs args)
{
    await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
    {
        alarm.Pause();
        Status.Text = "lolwtf";
    });
}
```

I'm trying to know when the user unlocks his computer.

**EDIT:** also the error I keep getting is:
Delegate to an instance method cannot have null 'this'. and it highlights:

```
lol.Unlocking += Lol_Unlocking;
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to know when the user unlocks his computer.

You can hookup a `SessionSwitchEventHandler`. Obviously your application will need to be running. **SessionSwitchEventHandler** delegate, you identify the method that will handle the event. To associate the event with your event handler, add an instance of the delegate to the event.

```
Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.SessionSwitch += new Microsoft.Win32.SessionSwitchEventHandler(SystemEvents_SessionSwitch);
void SystemEvents_SessionSwitch(object sender, Microsoft.Win32.SessionSwitchEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Reason == SessionSwitchReason.SessionLock)
    { 
        //I left my desk
    }
    else if (e.Reason == SessionSwitchReason.SessionUnlock)
    { 
        //I returned to my desk
    }
}
```

You can have a look on the [SessionSwitchReason Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.sessionswitchreason(v=vs.110).aspx) to find more about the uses the SessionSwitchReason class to represent the type of a session switch event.

> lol.Unlocking += Lol_Unlocking;

should be `lol.Unlocking += Lol_Unlocking(EventHandler_Unlocking);` and `EventHandler_Unlocking` has to be defined in the program.

my understanding for `LockApplicationHost.Unlocking` is that it helps to unlock and lock the device whereas to determine if the device is unlocked and unlocked `SessionSwitchEventHandler` will be better approach. For more understanding on the [LockApplicationHost.Unlocking check this](http://pastebin.com/mpwjBJ51)

Comment: I am unable to use your code in my universal windows app unfortunately. Is there any other way?

Comment: Also I just did what you suggested and I get a red underline underneath lol_unlocking and when I hover over it it says lol_unlocking doesn't exist in current context.